# Counting dashes in numbers

Tags: performance, haskell

I have written my very first Haskell module and I feel that the code can be improved based on the simplicity of the problem I am solving. Do you have any suggestions?

Problem statement:

```
You are given a String code containing a message composed entirely of decimal digits ('0'-'9'). Each digit consists of some number of dashes (see diagram below). A "check function" of a message is defined as the total number of dashes in the message. Return the value of the check function for the message represented in code.

Definition

Class:  CheckFunction
Method: newFunction
Parameters: String
Returns:    int
Method signature:   int newFunction(String code)
(be sure your method is public)


Notes
-   0 consists of 6 dashes, 1 consists of 2 dashes, 2 consists of 5 dashes, 3 consists of 5 dashes, 4 consists of 4 dashes, 5 consists of 5 dashes, 6 consists of 6 dashes, 7 consists of 3 dashes, 8 consists of 7 dashes, 9 consists of 6 dashes.

Constraints
-   code will contain between 1 and 50 characters, inclusive.
-   Each character in code will be a digit ('0'-'9').
```

Solution:

```
module Main where

import System.IO()
import Data.Char

-- Problem statement: https://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=4788
-- Method signature: int newFunction(String code)

newFunction :: String -> Int
newFunction input =
    let arr = [6, 2, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7, 6]
        x = [arr !! digitToInt (input !! x) | x <- [0..length input - 1]]
        in sum x

assert :: String -> Int -> String
assert s i = if newFunction s == i
then "test passed" else "test failed"


main :: IO()
main = do
  putStrLn $ show $ assert "13579" 21
  putStrLn $ show $ assert "868177" 28
  putStrLn $ show $ assert "8571" 17
  putStrLn $ show $ assert "3" 5
  putStrLn $ show $ assert "73254370932875002027963295052175" 157
```

Comment: Please include problem statement in the question (or your re-wording of it)

Comment: I have already included a link of the problem statement. Do you need more information?

Comment: it is a site policy we do not like relying on external website as they may go down and if they do our pages lose meaning Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Take items directly from the thing, without indexing:

```
x = [arr !! digitToInt i | i <- input]
```

And prefer `where` over `let`: (`where` is so much more common than `let`, it is easier to read as you see the general picture before the details.)

```
newFunction input = sum [arr !! digitToInt i | i <- input]
  where
    arr = [6, 2, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7, 6]
```

`arr` is a bad name, I would prefer `dashesInDigits`

`assert` should be more general (take `f` as argument) and written using guards.

Comment: Is it better to use " ^? element " from  lens package  instead of " !! "?

Comment: @Orestis in this case you may consider `lookup` that also works for non-number keys